# MSTest throws ‘System.TypeInitializationException’ when testing extension methods for a static class in c#

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, mstest

I have a static class called Helpers which contains a good number of simple helper methods including some simple extension methods on ‘string’ and the like:

```
public static string AddSquareBrackets(this string str)
{
     return "[" + str + "]";
}
```

I have a test class and method as follows:

```
[TestMethod()]
public void AddSquareBracketsTest()
{
     Assert.AreEqual("[NAME]", "NAME".AddSquareBrackets());
}
```

Static class declared with default (no coded) constructor:

```
namespace Equinoxe.Utilities.Helpers
{
    public static class HELPERS
    {
```

The call to the AddSquareBrackets throws the following:

```
System.TypeInitializationException was unhandled by user code
  Message=The type initializer for 'XXX.Utilities.Helpers.HELPERS' threw an exception.
  Source=XXX.Utilities
  TypeName=XXX.Utilities.Helpers.HELPERS
  StackTrace:
       at XXX.Utilities.Helpers.HELPERS.AddSquareBrackets(String str)
       at XXX.Utilities.Test.HELPERSTest.AddSquareBracketsTest() in C:\DEVELOPMENT\PROJECTS\XXX.NavEgate\XXX.Utilities.Test\HELPERSTest.cs:line 77
  InnerException: System.NullReferenceException
       Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
       Source=XXX.Utilities
       StackTrace:
            at XXX.Utilities.Helpers.HELPERS..cctor() in C:\DEVELOPMENT\PROJECTS\XXX.Utilities\XXX.Utilities\Helpers\HELPERS.cs:line 44
       InnerException:{System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at XXX.Utilities.Helpers.HELPERS..cctor() in C:\DEVELOPMENT\PROJECTS\XXX.Utilities\XXX.Utilities\Helpers\HELPERS.cs:line 44}
```

I have also looked

Im running VS2010

Comment: Please show the constructor of the `Utilities` class.

Comment: I don't know if this is meant to be a joke or not, but you didn't add the constructor to your question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a breakpoint at:

`C:\DEVELOPMENT\PROJECTS\XXX.Utilities\XXX.Utilities\Helpers\HELPERS.cs:line 44`

On that line, something is `null`, that should not be.

Comment: Thanks you pointed correctly. Line 44 populates a variable from the Web.Config file. Obviously the Web.Config file was not present in the test project. When added (by way of a link so I don’t have to update when original changes), all works. 
Many thanks for your help...